# Is there a method which runs when the simulator is closed from XCode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

This is purely for development purposes, because on the device you can use

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

But I often just hit the stop button in XCode to stop the simulator from running and I need some kind of method to run, so it can tell the database the the current player has stopped playing, any idea how to do that?

Comment: "But I often just hit the stop button in XCode" - that will terminate all the process immediately. Maybe you can look into [`atexit()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/atexit.html), but I can't guarantee for you it will indeed be called.

Comment: You should never rely on applicationDidEnterBackground: to do anything important as you can't be *sure* that the method will ever get called. If the app crashes, for example, that method will not get called at all. Maybe in this case it really isn't that important, just be aware of that fact. As for your question, I do not believe what you want is possible. Quitting the simulator is actually like doing a force shutdown on an actual device. It calls no method. (This is why you want to save data for the user constantly)

Comment: Where do you want the code to run — on iOS inside the simulator or on the host Mac?  If the latter, you could just write an app to watch for the simulator exiting.  If the former, you may be out of luck, as other answers have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I think this Apple Q&A will be interesting: [Detecting the Debugger](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2004/qa1361.html)

I found it mid-way through [this article](http://blog.noodlewerk.com/workflow/attaching-gdb-debugger-to-iphone-simulator/):

> Apple provided a little function to determine whether the debugger is attached here. So as soon as my application starts in the Simulator, I'll let it wait:
>
> ```
> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
>
> {
>
> #if DEBUG
>
> // Wait max. 10 secs for debugger to attach again:
>
> double waitTime = 0.0;
> while (AmIBeingDebugged() == NO &amp;&amp; waitTime &lt; 15.0)
> {
>     [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.25];
>     waitTime += 0.25;
> }
>
> #endif
> ```

Comment: The OP seems to be more interested in being able to run a piece of code before the simulator exits than simply detecting that (s)he's running on the simulator.